# C++ How to check if all values in array are different?

Tags: c++, loops, nested-loops

Hello I'm trying to check any values that are inputted in an array of any size are different. I am trying to use a nested loop for this code but cannot get a proper if statement to check that each value in the array are different. I'd appreciate any help!

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (unsigned k = i + 1; k < size; k++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[k]){
            return false;
        }
return true;
```

Ok thank you guys for the help your suggestions worked!

Comment: Your function will always return false since you will check element with itself when k == i. Change second loop to `unsigned k = i+1`.

Comment: Just perform sort and then, linearly, check for two identical subsequent values.

Comment: What is `i`? What purpose does `j` serve? It's not referenced inside the loop? Is this fake code? If so, why did you not post the real code? Details matter.

Comment: Just check if the input is in the array already before you add to the array, so you just need one for loop. If this is possible solution for you. Or even better use std::find to check if the input is already inside the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

```
 1. first loop should have j instead if i.

2. The second loop should start from i+1.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just made those changes to the program but it still returns values true on an array such as {1,2,1,3,4}

Answer (score 8):

Can you sort the `arr` first?

```
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
auto pos = std::adjacent_find(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
if (pos != std::end(arr))
    // we have a duplicate
```

Answer (score 2):

the first for-loop is wrong. There's a `j` instead of an `i`

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach..

```
//Implement an algorithm “Unique” to check if all elements of a given set of
//integers are distinct.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int arr[10] = {10, 20, 50, 90, 30, 60, 35, 40, 85, 90};
    int i, k, origVal = 0, newVal = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        origVal = arr[i];

        for (k = i+1; k < 10; k++)
        {

            if (origVal == arr[k])
            {
                newVal = 1;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (newVal ){break;}

    }

    if (newVal == 1)
    {
        cout<<"The Array does not contain completely distinct values"<<endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<< "The Array is distinct"<<endl;
    }

system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: this is inefficient. If I find two equal elements, why should I continue to loop in the array?

Comment: Good Point, I modified the answer. Thanks @Agostino

Comment: Using `std::sort` and `std::adjacent_find` is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use idiomatic c++ constructs?

```
if (std::equal(a1, a1 + sizeof a1 / sizeof *a1, a2))
```

where a1 and a2 are your two arrays.

I see the question got corrected with i only instead of i and j, which made me think it was two arrays. I'll leave this answer as a reference for using std::equal in versions prior to C++11. But for C+11, see Jens solution below. For that one has to include `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>`.

Comment: He has just one array and compares elements not complete arrays

Comment: @bazz-dee That's even more reason to not write your own loop. It is much easier to read because it has a name. I don't want to parse a for-loop to find out what the code is doing.

Comment: Could be even more C++: `std::equal( std::begin(a1), std::end(a1), std::begin(a2) )`

Comment: but he is looking for double entries inside of one array, not if two arrays are equal.

Answer (score 1):

A std::set contains only unique elements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 3, 5 };
    int b[] = { 1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 3 };

    std::set<int> sa(a, a + 9);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (sa.size() == (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a))); //all values not different

    std::set<int> sb(b, b + 6);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (sb.size() == (sizeof(b)/sizeof(*b))); //true, all values are different
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster and better approach would be to use map. For example

```
std::map<int, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (m[i] > 0) return false;
    m[i]++;
}
return true;
```

A one liner will look like this

```
return std::unique(arr, arr + size) == (arr + size);
```

Comment: `std::map` is not a hashmap, that's `std::unordered_map`

Comment: You have to sort the array before you can use `std::unique`.

Comment: And you may use a `set` instead of the `map`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort( std::begin(arr), std::end(arr) );
auto u = std::unique( std::begin(arr), std::end(arr) );
bool containsDuplicate = u != std::end(arr);
```

Comment: As in Bo Persson's answer, `std::adjacent_find` is better than `std::uniq`

Answer (score 1):

If your sequence is sorted and you want to get rid of the duplicates, or if you can afford to sort it or a copy of it, and then remove the duplicates, then you can use the std::unique standard library algorithm.

There are good examples at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique, but all you need to remember is that if you pass a sorted sequence without duplicates to std::unique, it'll return an iterator to the last element - usually end().

If it returns anything else, there are duplicates starting at the returned iterator, meaning that they were moved to *after* a sorted sequence of non-duplicates. You can then remove those, for instance with an std::vector you do v.erase(returnedIterator, v.end()).

Comment: As Bo Persson showed in his answer, there is also `std::adjacent_find` stops at the first duplicate.

Comment: Correct - std::unique is the answer when _all_ duplicates need finding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){

    int arr[] = {3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); // Finding length of array

    std::sort(arr, arr+len);

    int unique_elements = std::unique(arr, arr+len) - arr; // Finding number of unique elements

    if(unique_elements == 1) std:: cout << "All elements of this array are Equal\n";
    else std::cout << "All elements of this array are not Equal\n";

    return 0;
}
```